# undefined reference to a static function

Tags: c++

I have a strange problem when I create a static function in class A and I want to call it from class B function. I get

> undefined reference to `A::funcA(int)'

Here is my source code : 
a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

void funcA(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        static void funcA( int i );
};

#endif // A_H
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

void B::funcB(){
    A::funcA(5);
}
```

and b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "a.h"

class B
{
    public:
        B();
        void funcB();
};

#endif // B_H
```

I'm compiling with Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
#include "a.h"

void funcA(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

should be

```
#include "a.h"

void A::funcA(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Since `funcA` is a static function of your class `A`. This rule applies both to static and non-static methods.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to prefix the definition with the class name :

```
#include "a.h"

void A::funcA(int i) {
     ^^^
//Add the class name before the function name
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The way you did things, you defined an unrelated `funcA()`, ending up with two functions (namely `A::funcA()` and `funcA()`, the former being undefined).