# undefined reference to A::funcA(int)

Tags: c++, function, static

I am currently starting work on a project where i would have a file of shared tool functions which i can use without having to instance the class, i have read about using static functions for this so i decided to try to do the same. However i seem to keep getting an error of undefined reference to my static function. Looking for an answer I came upon several answers like the one in the following link but i still fail to compile my code:
[undefined reference to a static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727681/undefined-reference-to-a-static-function)

I decided to copy and paste the code given in the link above, a.cpp/.h and b.cpp/.h files, but even then i get compilation errors:
undefined reference to main [this error i can remove by adding a simple main function in b.cpp]
undefined reference to A::funcA(int)

Am i forgeting something when compiling? I am simply using g++ b.cpp am using g++ 4.7.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted the new question because i coudn´t comment on the existing answers of the one i quoted (need 50 reputation). You can close the question if its not useful thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from the linked question as an example: since the **definition** of the function `A::funcA(int)` is in `a.cpp`, you also need to include that source file in your compilation, like

```
g++ b.cpp a.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile `a.cpp` as well:

```
g++ b.cpp a.cpp
```

Otherwise the linker can't find the definition for `A::funcA` because it's located in `a.cpp`.